# Master Detail Design Suggestion

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to learn how to develop custom `UISplitViewController` and want to create design similar to this:

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

I am curious how to create the gap around the detail view, including the top of navigation bar.

Does it use `UISplitViewController` or just 2 different view that created manually to mimick `UISplitViewController`?

Anyone can give me suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot doesn't appear to be using a `UISplitViewController`. I guess these are just custom views.